# Machine Learning CNN: identifying by location rather than the image itself

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a binary classification problem where I need to find a relative location of something. I have a very small personal dataset and it is difficult to find a larger one. I'm attempting to identify a location of objects, such as a circle, which will produce a 'yes' or 'no' answer. When I run my train samples against itself, I can produce near 100% accuracy, but as soon as I introduce the testing samples, they score very poorly between 30-60%.

However, it is my understanding that CNNs will identify objects rather than locations of objects. For example, if you are searching for a sphere, it won't matter where it is, as long as it identifies features that describe a sphere.

Is there a way I can tune my algorithm to search for location rather than the object itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do such a thing. A very simple(naive baseline) way will be to predict a grid of values rather than a single number presence/absence. 
You can for example create a labeled set ; breaking up your images into a grid of boxes and labeling all the boxes which have your desired object (circle) with a 1 and other boxes to be 0

Of course there are much better way to  do this; look up image segmentation, mask RCNN 
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
They do object detection as well as segmentation ie. draw a bounding box around the object detected. The coordinates of the box would tell you where your object is located relatively in the image

Comment: Thank you so much! This information is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Great! Can you upvote my answer since it was useful